# Exception in Manual Loading of Spring Context in a Web Project

Tags: java, xml, spring, configuration

I am using multiple projects in a single .war and it successfully works in my tomcat.

When I try to load the spring context manually for testing, It gives exception while loading .xml from other projects.Below I am sharing the details of my project.

build tool : ANT

Context Loading method :

```
 ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("file:resources/spring/root-context.xml");
```

Exception :
**Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from URL [classpath:com/abc/service/config/test.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: com/abc/service/config/test.xml (No such file or directory)**

test.xml is part of core project and Loading via config Class.

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({
    "classpath:com/abc/service/config/test.xml",
    })
```

I could not understand why spring context loaded in tomcat and failed in manual loading. Please someone  help to figure out the problem.

Comment: Do you load the file referenced by classpath:com/abc/service/config/test.xml when runnning in tomcat? In production? Could it be that the file referenced by classpath:com/abc/service/config/test.xml resides under src/test/resources of the core project?

Comment: 1) Tomcat is not running while loading contex.   2)classpath:com/abc/service/config/test.xml  could not be under src/test/resources of the core project.

Comment: ad 2) Certainly. That is why I asked that. It might have been the cause of the problem.

Comment: Could you please show your complete context set-up? For the case it works? And for the case it does not work?

Comment: I would perhaps try to replace FileSystemXmlApplicationContext with some other one, even though I read the JavaDoc yesterday and in my understanding it shall has no problem resolving the referenced classpath:com/abc/service/config/test.xml via CLASSPATH.